# When converting one energy form into another will there be always at least two forms of energy resulting

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

when converting one energy form into another will there be always at least two forms of energy resulting.
 For example in following circumstances

**1.Conversion of electrical energy in toaster results in two form of energy(Heat and light energy)**

**2.Conversion of coal fuel to electricity in coal power station results in (electrical energy and heat energy)**

Is there any exclusion to this?(Like quantum thing)

Will it ever happen in real life or any related to that?

**THANK YOU**

Comment: Dropping a ball will cause potential energy to be converted into kinetic energy. And no more.

Comment: No steven some minute amount of energy will also be converted into heat energy when dropping a ball due to friction(Correct me if i am wrong )

Comment: Then imagine a ball dropped in space and being pulled towards a planet. No air to provide friction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general remark "when converting one energy form into another will there be always at least two forms of energy resulting" is not correct, as comments have stated before. If you added "in realistic cases", it would be more accurate. Ideal cases like elastic scatterring etc deal with conversion of kinetic energy to potential one with no other form of energy.

So let's see why this is happening in our real world. A general short answer would  be due to second law of thermodynamics. Specifically, the cases you mentioned are essentially about heat engines. The concept of a heat engine is that you have a hot reservoir and a cold one:
[image]

How to create the hot reservoir is matter of what energy form you use (for example if you burn coal, or use electricity to heat up a resistance, let's say). Then you take this energy to produce the "beneficial" work W( the reason that you are supposed to build this machine) that can be mechanical energy, for instance. But it might exist also some "unused" energy that ends up in low T reservoir(we will see that, this kind of energy always is present).

So we define something in order to define how efficient is this engine. Therefore the efficiency is defined as the ratio of $W/Q_h$. But we know that the (ideal) heat engine with the largest efficiency is given by Carnot one and the formula is given:
\begin{equation}
e=1-\frac{T_c}{T_h} 
\end{equation}
Notice that the $T_c,T_h$ are the temperatures that have the cold and hot reservoir, respectively and both temperatures are expressed in Kelvin. So according to the third law of thermodynamics, that is you cannot have zero (absolute) temperature, you can understand that you efficieny is always less than 1. So you always will have this "useless" $Q_c$. Therefore you always have two forms of produced energy(considering that you are interested in creating heat).

A more general answer, in order to understand what is the difference between ideal situations and the actual world is that the explicit form of second law of thermodynamics is $dS\geq 0$, where the equality refers to reversible processes, processes that don't take into consideration any side loss of energy due to  friction, for example. But this processes are not real and you always have some kind of this side effects.

Answer (score 0):

When an electron and a positron come to rest next to each other, the masses disappear and two photons appear, each with exactly the energy, $h\nu$, equal to the $mc^2$ of each particle.  That is, the mass energy is completely changed into electromagnetic energy.
$$m_{e^-}c^2+m_{e^+}c^2 \to 2h\nu = 1.022\text{ MeV}$$